# Why does `React.createElement()` create an object?

Tags: reactjs, dom

I'm learning *React* and I thought that `React.createElement(type, [props], [...children])` was just a method that encapsulates the *DOM* methods.

So, I thought that this *React* example: `React.createElement('h1', {className: 'greeting'}, 'Hello, world!')` would execute something like these statements:

```
const element = document.createElement('h1');
element.setAttribute('class', 'greeting');
document.createTextNode('Hello World');
```

However, I just read in their documentation that this method returns this object:

```
// Note: this structure is simplified
const element = {
  type: 'h1',
  props: {
    className: 'greeting',
    children: 'Hello, world!'
  }
};
```

Does anyone have more information about why it creates an object, and how does it communicate with the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html), read the [Fiber architecture guide](https://github.com/acdlite/react-fiber-architecture#readme), and view the [React DOM source](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/react-dom) for a very comprehensive understanding.

Essentially, React DOM acts as a mediator to reconcile the state of the DOM with those objects.