# Question about Diffing Algorithm in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn the general concept of virtual dom in React.

My assumption is as follows:

React uses virtual DOM to enhance performance. Virtual dom is a lightweight copy of the real DOM stored in memory. When there is a change of state or prop, React creates a virtual DOM. It uses the diffing algorithm to compare the previous virtual DOM with the updated virtual DOM. Lastly, it performs a process called reconciliation to determine which part of the real DOM needs to be updated and update it.

Here are a few questions that I have:

1. Does React has two Virtual DOMs? When I google, it said React only has 1 virtual DOM. So after it compares the previous virtual DOM with the updated virtual DOM, React automatically deletes the previous virtual DOM?
2. Another article I found online [here](https://medium.com/devinder/react-virtual-dom-vs-real-dom-23749ff7adc9) says that the diffing algorithm is the comparison of the real DOM with virtual DOM. So I am confused because many articles on google said diffing algorithm is the comparison of the previous virtual DOM and the updated virtual DOM.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70317627/438273), specifically the link to the Fiber architecture guide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes react maintains two virtual DOMs every time. The first one contains the updated virtual DOM, and the other is a pre-updated version of the updated virtual DOM. It compares the pre-updated version of the updated virtual DOM and finds what was changed in the DOM, like which components will be changed.

[Here you can see in details](https://www.javatpoint.com/what-is-dom-in-react)